# Get an html code from string and display it in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the body of an email stored in a javascript/typescript string (message.body). The content of that string is an html code like this:

`<div dir="ltr">test mail</div>`

I'm using angular bootstrap and I tried this code:

javascript/typescript code:

```
ShowMessage(message: MailMsg) {

    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MailModal, { centered: true });
    modalRef.componentInstance.msg = message;
    modalRef.componentInstance.body = $(message.body);

}
```

html code:

```
<div class="bodyMsg">
    <div type="text/html">{{body}}</div>
</div>
```

I'm getting this output: `[object Object]`

How can I propperly display the content of that initial message.body string?

Thanks

Comment: console log `message.body` in the `showMessage` method, you'll probably spot the problem.

Comment: @MikeS. console.log(message.body) outputs this or similar: ``` <div dir="ltr">test mail</div> ```

Comment: `or similiar`? Can you provide a screenshot? It is supposedly still an object and not a string so that can't be right.

Comment: with 'similar' i mean that it is always a html code in a string format. The output is never a formatted object.
BTW, i founded other solution. I post it bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we need a DomSanitizer instance in the class, so we declare it in the constructor:
`constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)`

And this is the code for converting the string to a SafeHtml object, that we can import to our html code:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const document = parser.parseFromString(mensaje.cuerpo, 'text/html');
modalRef.componentInstance.body = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(document.body.outerHTML);
```

The last thing missing is to tell out HTML that this code is not malicious and it's safe to display it with the [innerHTML] tag:

```
<div [innerHTML]="body"></div>
```

Working!

Answer (score 3):

Inject the string directly into the innerHTML prop of the component :

```
<div class="bodyMsg">
    <div [innerHTML]="body | safeHtml"></div>
</div>
```

but beware of XSS injection :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use "pre" tag in angular to render the HTML content as they were.

```
  <pre>{{ comments }}</pre>
```